# Trying to submit streamparse wordcount example on a local storm docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-storm, streamparse

I'm trying to use streamparse on a local cluster with docker containers

Here's my docker-compose.yml

`version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    nimbus:
    image: storm:1.0.2
    container_name: nimbus
    command: storm nimbus
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  supervisor:
    image: simsimy/docker-storm-supervisor-with-streamparse
    container_name: supervisor
    command: storm supervisor
    depends_on:
      - nimbus
      - zookeeper
  storm-ui:
    image: storm:1.0.2
    container_name: storm-ui
    command: storm ui
    depends_on:
      - nimbus
      - zookeeper
      - supervisor`

The streamparse sample is out of the box (created with the "sparse quickstart wordcount" command)

I just have changed some parameters in the wordcount quickstart example to match my storm version 1.0.2 (in project.clj file)

Btw, if you have any solution with another storm version, i can change mine

Here is my config.json :

`{
    "serializer": "json",
    "topology_specs": "topologies/",
    "virtualenv_specs": "virtualenvs/",
    "envs": {
        "prod": {
            "user": "",
            "ssh_password": "",
            "nimbus": "localhost",
            "workers": ["localhost"],
            "log": {
                "path": "",
                "max_bytes": 1000000,
                "backup_count": 10,
                "level": "info"
            },
            "use_virtualenv": true,
            "virtualenv_root": "/home/myhome/virtualenvs"
        }
    }
}`

./wordcount/virtualenvs/wordcount.txt contains only "steamparse" (out of the box config file)

When i run Sparse submit, the topology fails with the message :

`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/myhome/virtualenvs/wordcount/bin/streamparse_run" (in directory "/data/supervisor/stormdist/wordcount-10-1529168923/resources")`

I have checked the /data/supervisor/stormdist/wordcount-10-1529168923/resources directory, it only contains spouts and bolts...

The topology only works when i set "use_virtualenv": false

Here is the log file of the dependencies collect :
https://pastebin.com/Tf48kpBb

Any help would be very appreciated

Thanks

Comment: It seems i can't edit my post, so i wanted to add "Hello"  :D
Btw i wanted to say that if you have a solution with another storm version, i can change mine

Comment: You have your zookeeper that depends on zookeeper, it sounds strange. Where is your nimbus service? It's not in the yml you posted

Comment: the nimbus word is just under the "    container_name: zookeeper" line
indent issue during copy paste